# How do I cover invocable method in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, class

**I have a simple invocable method  that I'm calling from a Flow when certain criteria are met. I'm getting good results from the code as evidenced by reviewing data in the UI, but I'm not sure how to write a test class for an @InvocableMethod.
Here is the invocable method:**

```
@InvocableMethod
    public static void invocableUpdateAgentCache(List<List<String>> resultList) {
        ContactCentreCache__c cache = getUserCache();
        cache.Caller_Type__c = resultList[0][0];
        cache.ID_Check_Result__c = resultList[0][1];
        cache.Parent_ID__c = resultList[0][2];
        
        update cache;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome, please remember to provide more details, maybe a use case to allow us to get more insight into your question.

Comment: I think the question marked as a duplicate covers it. The short answer to many "How do I test thing X?" questions tends to be "_The same way you test anything else. Prepare the appropriate data, call the class/method directly, then assert against the results_".

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you get started, it's not meant to be 100% the solution to your inquiry, but I hope it helps you.

```
@IsTest
private class invocableUpdateAgentCache_Test {

    @TestSetup
    private static void testSetup() {
        <--- Build your Required Records here --->
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testBehavior() {
        <--- Do your logic here if needed --->
        List<ContactCentreCache__c> cache = [
                                            SELECT Id, Caller_Type__c,
                                            ID_Check_Result__c, Parent_ID__c
                                            FROM ContactCentreCache__c
                                            WHERE
                                            <Use Criteria to fetch data from the @TestSetup>];
        
        List<String> values = new List<String>();

        for (ContactCentreCache__c ccc : cache) {
            if(<VALIDATE DATA(nulls, etc)>) {
                  values.add(ccc.Caller_Type__c);
                  values.add(ccc.ID_Check_Result__c);
                  values.add(ccc.Parent_ID__c);
            }
        }

        List<List<String>> parameterTosend = new List<List<String>>{
            values 
        }
        
        Test.startTest();
        YourClass.invocableUpdateAgentCache(parameterTosend);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(<EXPECTED_RESULT>, <QUERY_TO_CHECK_ACTUAL_RESULT>);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to keep us posted.